# how point to the already installed sdk for Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-studio, installation

Normally i am using Eclipse for building the android Application. That's why i have latest android sdk installed in my PC. But now i want to move on Android Studio for building Android Application.

I have download the Android Studio and installed it. After installing it, it will launch for first time.

At that time it ask for the downloading the android-sdk, but as i have sdk already install in my PC, i have browse to that directory and link that path for the sdk.

but after that it still downloading the sdk for Android Studio. I don't want to download it and used already downloaded sdk.

Please help me for how to do that or what is the alternate to use already installed sdk for android studio?

Please check below image for the same.

When i point to the directory which is empty or the sdk is not available then it says like below:
[image]

But, if i select the directory where there is sdk already installed then it will not give me any message and i can able continue. but it start downloading the sdk.
[image]

After selecting Finish, it start downloading skd...
[image]

Now, i got stuck that what to do if i don't want to download it and directly access that sdk with in the Android Studio. Please help me for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not getting how to do that, but i can able to achieve what i want.

I have point to SDK path after first time installation of the Android Studio. My SDK is latest but still its updating it with screen i have posted in my question.

After some time the process get finished and i am able to use my same sdk for both Eclipse and Android Studio.

I guess Android Studio need some tools or framwork to be updated in the SDk that's why it is taking time to update it and then works fine.

Hope it will help to all other.

Enjoy Coding...   :)

Answer (score 2):

You can go on Custom and after that choose path to existing SDK, and Android Studio will tell you that only missing files will be installed, so if your SDK have all, he won't install anything.

Answer (score 1):

To map your already installed sdk path,

1. File->project Structure into Project Structure
2. Left > SDKs
3. SDK location select Android SDK location (old version use Press +, add another sdk)

Comment: but i have just installed Studio and its asking me in first launch. I am not able to go further without downloading or selecting specific path for it.

Comment: When you launch studio, we get a welcome page(Welcome to Android Studio). If you are getting this page, at the right side there is configure options. Select 'Project Defaults' > 'Project Structure'. Check if you can change the sdk path there.

Answer (score 0):

During first-time startup the setup wizard will offer to download the full Android SDK. Cancel the installation and choose to not rerun the wizard again.
You will be able to start the IDE and then in Preferences setup the path to your Android SDK and Java SDK.
It *may* offer to download some missing packages - in my case I had to download the "sources" package.
But at least it won't force you to download everything again.

Answer (score 0):

During the wizard flow (Android Studio 2.1), I selected "Custom install" then changed the Android SDK Location to where I have installed the SDK and got this output:

[image]

This shows that it is smart enough to recognize the standard Android SDK and not re-download everything.